# $C^1$ functions on an open connected set and local Lipschitz continuity

Tags: real-analysis

This question is related to the [previous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/941949/9464) one.

> Let $\Omega$ be an open connected subset of ${\bf R}^n$ and $f:\Omega\to{\bf R}^n$ be continuously differentiable such that
>   $$
> \sup_{x\in\Omega}||Df(x)||<+\infty. 
> $$
>   Show that for every compact $K\subset \Omega$, there exists $L_K$ such that for every $x,y\in K$,
>   $$
> |f(x)-f(y)|\leq L_K|x-y|. 
> $$

---

Here are some thoughts about it. If $\Omega$ is convex, then one can apply the theorem quoted in the previous question. Suppose it is not. By the compactness of $K$, one can cover it with finitely many open balls contained in $\Omega$. Since open balls are convex, one can have a Lipschitz constant $L_i$ for each ball. For any $x,y\in K$, if they are in the same open ball, then one can bound $|f(x)-f(y)|$ using the maximum of $\{L_i\}$. But when they are not in the same ball, I don't see how to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumption may be different but [the same proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/154753/) works.

Suppose $f$ is not Lipschitz on $K$. Then there exist two sequences $x_n,y_n\in K$ such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|}{|x_n-y_n|}= \infty \tag{1}$$ Passing to a subsequence, we can assume $x_n\to x\in K$.

Since $f$ is bounded on $K$, the numerator in (1) is bounded; therefore the denominator tends to zero. This means $y_n\to x$. So, for sufficiently large $n$ the points $x_n,y_n$ both lie in an open ball $B$ centered at $x$ and such that $\overline{B}\subset \Omega$.  But $B$ is convex, which allows for the argument you mentioned: 
$$|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|\le |x_n-y_n|\sup_{\overline{B}} \|Df\|$$
a contradiction.