# Is a function with uniformly continuous derivatives on a bounded regular domain also uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative, uniform-continuity

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded connected set which is **regular open**, meaning that $\textrm{int }\textrm{cl }\Omega = \Omega$. Suppose that $f\in C^1(\Omega)$ has **uniformly continuous** partial derivatives on $\Omega$. Is it necessary that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\Omega$?

If $\Omega$ is not assumed to be regular open the result would be false; an example can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/941949/functions-with-bounded-derivatives-on-a-open-convex-set). If the partial derivatives of $f$ are only suppose to be bounded then we can construct a counterexample as follows: let $$\Omega = ((-1,0)\times (0,1))\cup\left(\displaystyle{\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N^*}}} [0,1)\times \left(\dfrac{1}{2n},\dfrac{1}{2n-1}\right) \right)$$
Define $f|_{(-1,0)\times (0,1)} = 0$, $f|_{[0,1)\times \left(\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{2n-1}\right)} = (-1)^n x^2$, then $f_x$ is bounded by $2$, but $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

I believe that there are still counterexamples even when $\Omega$ is regular open have $f$ has uniformly continuous partial derivatives, but I couldn't find an example. Any help appreciated.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio bounded partial derivative cannot guarantee Lipschitz continuity in general if dimension is $>1$; please see my example (and please tell me if it is wrong).

Comment: Oh, I see. That was silly of me thank you. If $\Omega$ can be unbounded, then $f(x)=x^2$ has uniformly continuous derivative on $\Omega=\Bbb R$, but it isn't uniformly continuous.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Oh yes, $\Omega$ is supposed to be bounded. Thanks for your reminder :)

Comment: In a word, _no_. Take Daniel Fischer's example in the linked question, but instead of an annulus with a slit, imagine the region between two circles that are interiorly tangent.

Comment: For the record, isn't the $\Omega$ you've written actually regular open? If it were with $(1/n, 1/(n-1))$ then it wouldn't be, but with $\left(\frac1{2n},\frac1{2n-1}\right)$ its closure should be $([-1,0]\times [0,1])\cup([-1,1]\times\{0\})\bigcup_{n\ge 1} [0,1]\times\left[\frac1{2n}, \frac1{2n-1}\right]$ whose interior is again $\Omega$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I've written $\left(\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{2n-1}\right)$, right?

Comment: @JianingSong You did. But the derivatives aren't unformly continuous, though.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Wow, that's very easy and powerful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio AndrewD.Hwang has provided an answer. Thanks for paying attention to the question :)